# Hide empty folders in OpenFileDialog window

Tags: powershell

I want to hide empty folders in `OpenFileDialog` window or change/hide the "No items match your search." message when browse to a empty folder.

```
    $FileBrowser = [Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog]@{
        Title = "Choose a file"
        InitialDirectory = $PWD
        CheckFileExists = $FALSE
    }
    if ($FileBrowser.ShowDialog() -eq "OK") {
        $FilePath = $FileBrowser.FileName

        ...

    }
```

Comment: Maybe? What does your code look like? How are you calling OpenFileDialog? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @EBGreen I see "filter" is not the solution. I have no idea now. I just call a [Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog] object.showDialog() method normal, no special code.

Comment: Please post your actual code in your question as an edit. Also, this is really a .Net question not a powershell question.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [ask] to see what your question is missing.

Comment: I have edited my question. Take a look, thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure that there isn't any way to do this as the class exists. You will have to roll your own. As I said, this is really a .Net question ***not*** a powershell question.